# How to choose Drain current for a JFET Differential Amp

Tags: jfet

I have to design a JFET differential amplifier with a current mirror. I am unsure where to start and what to set the biasing current to. Any help will be appreciated to point me in the right direction. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the drain current will affect if it increases/decreases? If not, you'll need to start with small signal models of transistors and work your way up.

Answer (score 0):

My first engineering manager was also designing zero_temperature_coefficient high CMRR instrumentation amplifiers, and his super_tech (no degree but very skilled) would hand_select the Iddq of the JFET diff_pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start by finding a good matched pair of jfets ! That's the biggest challenge. Vgs characteristics of jfets are notoriously wide, I recall looking for a matched pair (a dual) in a can some decades ago. They were as rare as hen's teeth then and fabulously expensive !

The challenge with jets is Vgs matching for differential amplifier applications. It's tricky, so costs a lot.

A quick browse found Interfet's IFN411 (~£10 from Mouser) which only guarantees matching to 20mV. It'll need a trimpot in your circuit for DC amplifier applications. Prices only go *UP* from here btw.

As regards operating current, choose your fet first and choose some sensible percentage of Idss. Low noise amplifiers will operate at higher values of Id than you might consider normal. Certainly between several and several tens of mA.

Comment: [2SK389 is resurrected](http://www.linearsystems.com/lsdata/datasheets/201122%20-%20LSK389%20Datasheet%20Rev%20A14%202018%2006%2014.pdf)